# Xperia SP boot loop into flash mode

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-sp

I have an Xperia SP, and it's stuck in a boot loop after some faulty manipulation. I only see Sony's logo, and plugging the phone to my laptop sets it to `flash mode` automatically for around 20 seconds, before restarting to connect again straight into `flash mode`.

How can I fix my phone?

Comment: On SE sites, it's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question), even [our help center states so](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) – but answers should be posted as answers, not as part of the question-post (and answers will be "accepted" here instead of prefixing the title with "FIXED" – we're [not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/192154)). Mind [edit]ing that out of your question, and move it to a separate answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fix this in a minute

Comment: Great, thanks! Just hoping you pick the right minute (not one too far into the future ;) // Btw, as pointed out: consider "accepting" your answer then (clicking the check-mark next to it), so it shows up as "working solution".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this boot loop issue, start by flashing [this kernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2646193) via FlashTool, switching your phone into `fastboot mode`. The best is to follow [the original guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2646193) I guess.

Then, you can follow [this tutorial](http://theunlockr.com/2014/04/29/install-custom-rom-sony-xperia-sp/) to install a custom .zip file ROM again, allowing your phone to boot again. You might need to upload the .zip file directly onto your SD card.

I hope this helps.